# Multiple C++ Main Files Within a Single Visual Studio Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am just beginning my journey in C++ programming (coming from many other languages). Because I am learning the basics, I would like to store many simple C++ programs in a single project. Each of these simple console type applications will contain a main function.

When creating an empty C++ project, Visual Studio creates 15 files which comes to 546KB. To save room on my computer, it would be best to have sub-folders within this single project for each small C++ program for learning purposes.

Is it possible to break different console based programs up into separate folders within the same Visual Studio C++ project? I am using VS 2017 Community Edition.

**Edit**:
I understand that you can create a VS Solution with multiple projects within. The reason why I don't want to do this is explained above. 546KB is a lot of space to allocate just for running a small console application. It would be best to have many programs that can run independently within a single project. Is there a way in VS to choose which main function to call out of all of the main C++ files?

Comment: You should have 1 solution, which can have many projects. This way, if you choose each project to have it's own folder, you will have the folder layout you are requesting.

Comment: Just have a single main function and each subprogram in its own function. Call the subprogram in the main function.

Comment: See question edit for why I don't want to use many projects within a single solution.

Comment: If you are worried about disk usage you really shouldn't be using Visual Studio. Use something more lightweight.

Comment: @john what would you recommend?

Comment: I use Visual Studio, so I'm not up with the alternatives. A lot of people use Code::Blocks, but don't take that as a personal recommendation.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/getting-started-with-visual-studio-for-c-and-cpp-development/

Answer (score -1):

You can use separate project Configuration for each main function that you've got in your project (e.g. create project Configurations named Main1 and Main2). Then you can conditionally include the .cpp file that implements the relevant main function by editing your .vcxproj file, e.g.:

```
<ClCompile Include="main1.cpp" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Main1'" />
<ClCompile Include="main2.cpp" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Main2'" />
```

That will include main1.cpp only for a Configuration named Main1 and main2.cpp only for a Configuration named Main2.

I'd **not recommend** that though because Visual Studio 2017 does not update the Solution Explorer correctly when you switch the current configuration and you'll need to reload the project to see the current files.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! This answer solves the problem but as I've said - it's not recommended because of UI issues however I could not downvote myself :)

Comment: Just a heads up, it wasn't me that down voted. Your answer is very appreciated. I have decided in the time being that I will most likely use something more light weight such as the Visual Studio Command Line tools.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of conditional inclusion use the Excluded from build property to exclude files that shouldn't be compiled as part of the current configuration. This will show all files in solution explorer but only include the appropriate files when the build is actually performed. This is a bit backwards but works nicely with the UI. It has the additional benefit of being something the VS property editor can do without needing to open and manually edit the vcproj file.

The Excluded from build property is found on the file properties  Configuration properties -> General. Open solution explorer (View->Solution explorer) right click on the file and that pane should be the default.